# Is it possible to use Upnp service in cordova platfom with many os platforms target(android, ios)

Tags: android, ios, cordova, plugins, upnp

I'm developing a `cordova` application witch i need to use `Upnp service`, what i find a plugin works with only blackberry10 target platform :

https://github.com/blackberry/WebWorks-Community-APIs/tree/master/BB10-Cordova/UPnP#readme

what i need simply a plugin works with at least with android and ios platforms)
any help please.

Comment: Have you looked at connectsdk?